# gracenote sdk for music id not working on iOS 7 device

Tags: gracenote

here is what we have done:

we added the framework to our project and

have the following in one of our classes:

**GCSearchViewController.h**

```
@interface GCSearchViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate, GNSearchResultReady, GNAudioSourceDelegate>
```

**GCSearchViewController.m**

```
// - As per the web tutorial

#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNConfig.h>

#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNOperations.h>

#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNSearchResponse.h>

#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNSearchResult.h>

// - As per what we saw in the demo app

#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNRecognizeStream.h>

#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNAudioConfig.h>

#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNAudioSourceMic.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>


…


#pragma mark - Gracenote Delegate


-(void) identifySong {

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL response){

NSLog(@"Allow microphone use response: %d", response);

if (response) {

[GNOperations recognizeMIDStreamFromMic:self config:self.config];


}

}];

}


- (void) GNResultReady:(GNSearchResult *) result

{

GNSearchResponse *best = [result bestResponse];

if (![result isFailure] && (best.artist!=nil)) {

NSLog(@"Artist %@", best.artist);

NSLog(@"Song name %@", best.trackTitle);

} else {

NSLog(@"No Match");

}

}


- (void) audioBufferDidBecomeReady:(GNAudioSource*)audioSource samples:(NSData*)samples {

NSError *err;

err = [self.recognizeFromPCM writeBytes:samples];



if (err) {

NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",[err localizedDescription]);

}

}
```

this code works ok in the simulator, but whenever we run it on the device (ipod touch 5th or iphone 5) the app breaks with the following error:

```
2013-11-16 22:00:40.402 GC[1758:60b] 22:00:40.401 ERROR: [0x3c29f18c] >aurioc> 783: failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 1 ch, 44100 Hz, Int16>)

Error: 0xffffd59d2013-11-16 22:00:52.904 Leaf[1758:60b] Allow microphone use response: 1

2013-11-16 22:00:52.925 GC[1758:60b] 22:00:52.925 ERROR: [0x3c29f18c] >aurioc> 783: failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 1 ch, 44100 Hz, Int16>)

Error: 0xffffd59d2013-11-16 22:00:52.927 GC[1758:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[GNFingerprinterQueue startupTimerFired], /home/mobile/z-15003-ecma-3.2/cddb-clients/mmid/iOSMobileSDK/3.2/Classes/Private/GNFingerprinterQueue.m:291

2013-11-16 22:00:52.930 GC[1758:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'audioSource is nil'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x2fb66f4b 0x39e7b6af 0x2fb66e25 0x3050efe3 0x151849 0x1520e5 0x3054ae9b 0x2fb32183 0x2fb31653 0x2fb2fe47 0x2fa9ac27 0x2fa9aa0b 0x3478a283 0x3233e049 0x7b621 0x3a383ab7)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

our app is targeting iOS7... appreciate any pointers on how to make it work

Comment: Please check answer on below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144459/audiounitinitialize-returns-10851-kaudiouniterr-invalidpropertyvalue/42129758#42129758

Answer (score 2):

This is an error with acquiring the Microphone hardware. The error log:

**2013-11-16 22:00:40.402 GC[1758:60b] 22:00:40.401 ERROR: [0x3c29f18c] >aurioc> 783: failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 1 ch, 44100 Hz, Int16>)**

Above error happens in two cases:

1. Microphone Hardware was not configured correctly OR
2. RemoteIO was unable to acquire hardware.

This is typically happens with Simulator but can happen on the device if the microphone is inaccessible. The error can also happen if AVAudioSession is not correctly configured or is messed up. Check AVAudioSession configuration and Try deleting the iOS app, re-installing it and doing a clean build.

Comment: Please answer on this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144459/audiounitinitialize-returns-10851-kaudiouniterr-invalidpropertyvalue/42129758#42129758